# PHP dump $_REQUEST to file

Tags: php

I want to dump request variables to a file for debugging. How's this possible?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
<?php
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);
```

Untested but should do the job, just change request.log to the file you want to write to.

Comment: Tiny insignificant detail, but Forgot your closing ?>

Comment: Closing ?> is not necessary, at all. Indeed it's best practice when writing libraries/etc (not that this is relevant here) to omit it so as to ensure no accidental output of whitespace that could mess up output buffering/headers/etc.

Comment: I like `var_export($var,true)` personally.

Comment: @josh A closing ?> isn't necessary, actually its not good practice. You can get extra whitespace after the closing tag which can cause errors in your script

Comment: I used `fwrite($fp, '['.date("c").']'.$req_dump."\n");` instead. this way while I `tail -f`the file, I get a date / time stamp.

Comment: This didn't write any request headers to disk, only querystring values.

Answer (score 30):

I think nowadays this method is easier and faster:

```
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, true);
$fp = file_put_contents('request.log', $req_dump, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: You'll likely want to append to the log:

`file_put_contents( 'request.log', $req_dump, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: Why do you need the `$fp` variable here?

Comment: You don't **need** it, but it will contain `true` or `false` value depending on whether the action was successful.

Answer (score 5):

Use `serialize()` function for dumping. Dump `$_SERVER`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_POST` and `$_GET` separately (may go to the same file). If you're planning on debugging with the data it helps to know if the data was part of a POST request or a GET request.

Dumping everything is good for debugging in development, but not so in production. If your application does not have many users, it can work in production too. If you anticipate many users, consider dumping just the `$_POST` data, or limit server variables to those starting with HTTP_.

Answer (score 5):

```
/* may be late but he can help others.
it's not my code, I get it from : 
https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40
*/

            class DumpHTTPRequestToFile {
                public function execute($targetFile) {
                    $data = sprintf(
                        "%s %s %s\n\nHTTP headers:\n",
                        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
                        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                        $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
                    );
                    foreach ($this->getHeaderList() as $name => $value) {
                        $data .= $name . ': ' . $value . "\n";
                    }
                    $data .= "\nRequest body:\n";
                    file_put_contents(
                        $targetFile,
                        $data . file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n"
                    );
                    echo("Done!\n\n");
                }
                private function getHeaderList() {
                    $headerList = [];
                    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
                        if (preg_match('/^HTTP_/',$name)) {
                            // convert HTTP_HEADER_NAME to Header-Name
                            $name = strtr(substr($name,5),'_',' ');
                            $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
                            $name = strtr($name,' ','-');
                            // add to list
                            $headerList[$name] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return $headerList;
                }
            }
            (new DumpHTTPRequestToFile)->execute('./dumprequest.txt');

            // add this line at the end to create a file for each request with timestamp

            $date = new DateTime();
            rename("dumprequest.txt", "dumprequest" . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . ".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php //log

$razdelitel = '--------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

$data_REQUEST = '$_REQUEST: ' . print_r($_REQUEST, true).PHP_EOL;
$data_POST = '$_POST: ' . print_r($_POST, true).PHP_EOL;
$data_GET = '$_GET: ' . print_r($_GET, true).PHP_EOL;

$data_all = $razdelitel . $data_REQUEST . $data_POST . $data_GET;

$name_txt = __DIR__ . '/log_' . date('m.Y') . '.txt'; //log_12.2021.txt


$chmod = '0244';
chmod($name_txt, $chmod); 

file_put_contents($name_txt, $data_all, FILE_APPEND);
//var_dump($name_txt, $chmod); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.