# Why just empty row appears if input data to localhost using android device?

Tags: android, mysql, ip, localhost

I'm new at android. I want to input data to localhost. App already used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">` and url already used same network address.
If run on emulator, data can saved to localhost. And if run on physical android device, one table row appear but data can't save, just empty row.

My PC use WLAN from sharing data connection on my android device. So, i write url like this:`private static String url = "http://192.168.43.62/android/insert_indo_tidak_ditemukan.php";` Why just empty row appears if using android device? or my JSON parser can't send data if use physical android device?

JSONParser.java:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {

        if (method == "POST") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

Comment: If you're running the same code on emulator and device then it should work fine. The fact that you get an empty row means that the call actually reached the server, and hence it inserted an empty row. Try checking this, log your values just right before sending to ensure they're available, and debug the parameters you get on the server side as soon as you get the request to check if you received the data or not.

Comment: One thing just to clarify, is the issue of the server not writing to the database, or the client (your app) not receiving any data from the server?

Comment: just server not writing to database. I dont get how to check that.

Comment: In your `makeHttpRequest` method, write the `params` values to the logcat to ensure the values are being passed correctly, I'm not familiar with PHP but it should be pretty easy to sort of "console.log" the parameters you receive in the request, log that and see if your values got sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how i can check from physical device? sending data to mysql use emulator already work, but if in physical device doesn't work, just empty row.

Comment: The only things you need to do are make sure: 1. both your PC/Server and your phone are connected on the same network. 2. Your server should be running on "0.0.0.0" NOT "127.0.0.1 or Localhost". 3. ipconfig in MSDos commandline, get your IPv4 address (That's your PC IP) and use that in your phone as URL. If you got those set, then your device can reach your server, then just verify if the parameters are passed or not through debugging the requests.

Comment: This might be of help to see the incoming requests in PHP, see if you're getting any data or not, or if the request is even reaching the server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328189/php-dump-request-to-file